# Change CSS onclick function javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code in which when I click on particular element its background should change by removing all other elements background.But the problem here I am getting is when I click on li under ul li ul its taking parent li also and giving background. And Please check my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul li ul li").click(function() {  

 //a = $(this).html();         // when clicking any of these links
 //alert(a);
$("*").removeClass("active"); // remove highlight from all links
$(this).addClass("active");          // add highlight to clicked link
})
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul li").click(function() {  

//a = $(this).html();         // when clicking any of these links
//alert(a);
$("*").removeClass("active"); // remove highlight from all links
$(this).addClass("active");          // add highlight to clicked link
})
});
</script>

<style>
.active { color:white; background:green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>level1
        <ul>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li>bbb</li>
        <li>ccc</li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li>level2</li>
<li>level3</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrCqU/1/) for this kind of thing, makes our lives easier. Did this one for you.

Comment: `$("*").removeClass("active");` should be replaced with `$(".active").removeClass("active");` as it's way more efficient.

Comment: @jfriend00 changed * to .active but still no changes

Comment: @user2720197 - I wasn't suggesting my change would fix your problem.  I can't understand your question so I have no idea what you problem is.  But, what I've suggested is a much better way to remove all existing `active` classes if that's part of your eventual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your event is propagating to the parent, so the code is being executed first in the click handler for the child `ul li` and then again in the click handler for the parent `ul li`.

Add a call to `event.stopPropagation()` in the child's handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").click(function(evt) {  
        $(".active").removeClass("active"); // remove highlight from all links
        $(this).addClass("active");          // add highlight to clicked link
        evt.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrCqU/4/)

---

Alternatively, if you need events to propagate elsewhere, but not be handled in this code you can compare `event.target` to `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").click(function(evt) {  
        if(evt.target !== this) return; //do not process on bubbled-up events

        $(".active").removeClass("active"); // remove highlight from all links
        $(this).addClass("active");          // add highlight to clicked link
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrCqU/5/)

Comment: When i click on first ul li its taking all its child li and giving background...but working fine with the child li's..So when i click on parent li only parent element should be highlighted

Comment: You mean you want only the line clicked to apply the style? You'll have to manually reset the children's style then. Try adding `.active * { color:black; background:white;}` to your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/TrCqU/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a simple manner,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").on('click',function() {  
        $(this).parent('ul').find('li').removeClass("active");// get all li from the parent ul
        $(this).addClass("active");// add highlight to clicked link
    });
});
```

If you want to remove all `active classes` from all `li's` then try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").on('click',function() {  
        $('li').removeClass("active");// remove active class from all li's
        $(this).addClass("active");// add highlight to clicked link
    });
});
```

Comment: @user2720197 test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to your script :

> jquery 10 version

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li ul li').on('click', function() {
        $('ul li ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

oops sorry if you use lower version of jquery

> jquery 1.3 will be fine

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul li ul li').live('click', function() {
            $('ul li ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

> **EDIT**

Do you want something like this :

```
var Test = {
    init:function() {
        $('ul li').click(function() {
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).children().css({
                'background' : '#fff',
                'color' : '#000'
            });
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    Test.init();
});
```

Comment: You can choose based on what jquery version you use

Comment: Do you also want to have the parent an active class?

Answer (score 0):

It is working as charm

Need a change at line 21 in your code.

Use:

```
$("ul li ul li").click(function() {
```

instead of

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
```